# Weird Electrical Issue In Garage

Tags: circuit-breaker

Hi I have a question and I was hoping to get some insite. First I am getting a certified electrician to come check it out on Thursday but figured let me do my homework.

So I noticed the other day my garage lost power. Looking into it none of the breakers tripped and the feed coming from the house was fine too.

I checked the panel in the garage and noticed off the bat the previous owner didn’t use the correct cable to run to 240v in. He just used a 120volt cable and used the black and white cable as hots and the ground as a neutral. I know that was stupid of them. I also noticed one of the legs doesn’t get power so I know that there is a break along the way?

I removed that cable from the house to isolate it away. And only used the other leg since I was getting 120 on it.

However anything I plug in that has a load causes it to blink. Ex a light bulb just blinks nonstop. Almost like a short (before the garage on the boot legged cable) but none of the breakers trip

I’m curious what could be causing the other leg to have issues only under load. I’m thinking the cables are grounding to themselves but if so I would expect the 240v circuit breaker in the house to trip.

For now I killed the breaker in the house just in case.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: My experience is that if corners were cut in one area, they were likely cut elsewhere.  Who knows what lies between the box and the garage?  You've done the right thing by calling in a professional at this point.

Comment: Exactly I wonder if the cable wasn’t run in conduits and is just buried in the ground. I’m not a electrician but I am a nerd and know cutting corners is just stupid. It makes me think there is a very heavily cut cable and it’s barely making a connection and is causing it. I haven’t seen any other issues in the house so for now. I will leave it off in the house. It’s scary to think there is a short somewhere in my yard.

Comment: Probably not a short, or the breaker would be tripping but could very well be an open-circuit.  Possibly an improperly done splice buried in the wall that has come loose.  I'd definitely leave it OFF until it's checked out and be thankful you didn't have a fire or get someone injured.

Comment: Is the cable a UF (no paper separator) or a NM (paper separator between the jacket and the wires) cable?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Good question; keep the information coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: If the cable was UF type usually gray or black and installed prior to 1999 code it could have been legal, there is no such thing as 120v cable romex or UF cable has been rated for 600v for years, and this was quite common prior to the 99 code change that added the requirement for the 4 wire feed and ground rod if a detached garage.

Comment: Hi All from what I can tell it’s UF cable not sure the gauge but it’s 2 plus ground cable. Ed what makes me concerned is the ran two legs of 120 off of a cable designed for 120. They used the hot (black) white (neutral) as the two hots and the ground (bare cable) as the neutral. I’m still learning about electricity but from my understanding without a proper ground the circuit breaker in the garage sub panel would never trip if there is no ground? Unless the sub panel is bonded to the neutral? which is still bad?

Comment: @dogboyaa1 -- what loads are present at this subpanel?

Comment: Hi threephaseeel the loads in the garage are, a old fridge, garage door opener, about 4  fluorescent lights. Not sure about the amps though. I know off the bat the main circuit breaker has a 60 amp 240v going to the sub panel. Safe to assume I’m not using anywhere near that.

Comment: @dogboyaa1 -- are any of the loads 240V? (i.e. are there any two-pole breakers in the garage subpanel?)

Comment: Sorry for the delay in answering.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in answering. There are two pole but nothing really needed 240 at least not when I moved in. I did learn something else that makes sense. They are borrowing power from the well pump as the there is a split that goes to the pump (actually goes to a 20 amp circuit breaker next to a pressure switch). Interesting that if I cut the 20amp going to the pump I still have problems. It tells me the issue is between the main panel to the junction between the pump and garage. Solution is to separate the two and run correct 6-3 uf cable to the garage.

Comment: @dogboyaa1 -- no problem whatsoever.  So, there are two pole breakers in the garage subpanel, but no 240V loads? Interesting...and noted on the dodgy hijacking of the well pump circuit; with that, I think you have the right fix in mind :)

Comment: Ha yeah it’s very obvious now that they used the pumps cable to extend to the garage. It now makes sense why their was no ground to the garage and there must be a short in the crawl space where they spliced in. I’m renting so landlord promised to get the pump fixed this week and the garage in a month or so. If anything I learned so much that I was able to diagnose a neutral and ground swap at work today. I’m an it guy and the engineer chef was surprised I figured it out

Comment: So. Quick Hilarious update. An electrician came in and split the garage from the well pump. Putting the well on a 30 amp circuit with new UF cable. No more trips. But the Garage still has issues and he couldn’t pull the bad cable as it’s stuck in the conduit. As soon as any load gets put on the voltage drops to 60ish volts. So my guess it’s a damaged cable in the conduit. He will have to come back and dig and figure out where the jam is. At least I have water now